# json to series then transpose works straight df does not

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge json that I want to turn to df, where the keys are the indexes (so df with one line basically and when the value is a list the cell will contain that list)
My json sometimes contains a list in the value so straight pd.DataFrame(json) doesn't work for me,
but when i use pd.Series(json).to_frame().transpose() it does work.
Does someone know if there any way to do it with a simple flag to DataFrame?
Or am I stuck with the long way using Series
json example:
js = {"name": null, "supported": null, "mismatch": 0.7645600991325898, "feature": ['04eb2514723dbea9695d3deb2d1f6b20'], "type": []}

Comment: Without a sample of your input and desired output - difficult to comment.  have you looked at `pd.json_normalize()` ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html